# Black and yellow insect on lavender

Tags: insects

I'm trying to identify the following bug on a lavender plant.

[image: bug picture 1]

[image: bug picture 2]

Theres about a half dozen of them and they appear to have six legs and a long abdomen. They're black with yellow or orange sides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a larva of a ladybird (ladybug, Coccinellidae), they are actually good if you want to get rid of Aphids or others leaf suckers. Adult ladybugs are known to eat aphids, and they are often used for biological control of pests. The larva eat actually much more aphids, so cherish this little larva!

Comment: Aha. Hello ladybird friend. Thanks!